# draw dot on linechart in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, linechart

I have a line series in a linechart and a slider that goes from 0 to 200. When I now move the slider, I want to have a dot appearing at the chart so when I move the slider to 150, there should be a dot where the x-coordinate of the chart is 150.
Has anybody an idea? I did not found anything.

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to extend the linechart class and program it to handle your dot on its own. There is no built in functionality to do this. It would probably be difficult, you may want to create your own linechart component using sprites and graphics to draw the dots, lines, etc.... if anything it may be a fun project to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Drawing on charts](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_formatting_02.html)